# Broken Pipe Error causes streaming Elastic MapReduce job on AWS to fail

Tags: python, hadoop, amazon-web-services, mapreduce, elastic-map-reduce

Everything works fine locally when I do as follows:

```
cat input | python mapper.py | sort | python reducer.py
```

However, when I run the streaming MapReduce job on AWS Elastic Mapreduce, the job does not complete successfully.  The `mapper.py` runs part way through (I know this because of writing to `stderr` along the way).  The mapper is interrupted by a "Broken Pipe" error, which I'm able to retrieve from the syslog of the task attempt after it fails:

```
java.io.IOException: Broken pipe
    at java.io.FileOutputStream.writeBytes(Native Method)
    at java.io.FileOutputStream.write(FileOutputStream.java:282)
    at java.io.BufferedOutputStream.write(BufferedOutputStream.java:105)
    at java.io.BufferedOutputStream.flushBuffer(BufferedOutputStream.java:65)
    at java.io.BufferedOutputStream.write(BufferedOutputStream.java:109)
    at java.io.DataOutputStream.write(DataOutputStream.java:90)
    at org.apache.hadoop.streaming.io.TextInputWriter.writeUTF8(TextInputWriter.java:72)
    at org.apache.hadoop.streaming.io.TextInputWriter.writeValue(TextInputWriter.java:51)
    at org.apache.hadoop.streaming.PipeMapper.map(PipeMapper.java:109)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapRunner.run(MapRunner.java:50)
    at org.apache.hadoop.streaming.PipeMapRunner.run(PipeMapRunner.java:36)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.runOldMapper(MapTask.java:441)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.run(MapTask.java:377)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.Child$4.run(Child.java:255)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:396)
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1059)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.Child.main(Child.java:249)


2012-03-26 07:19:05,400 WARN org.apache.hadoop.streaming.PipeMapRed (main): java.io.IOException: Broken pipe
    at java.io.FileOutputStream.writeBytes(Native Method)
    at java.io.FileOutputStream.write(FileOutputStream.java:282)
    at java.io.BufferedOutputStream.write(BufferedOutputStream.java:105)
    at java.io.BufferedOutputStream.flushBuffer(BufferedOutputStream.java:65)
    at java.io.BufferedOutputStream.flush(BufferedOutputStream.java:123)
    at java.io.DataOutputStream.flush(DataOutputStream.java:106)
    at org.apache.hadoop.streaming.PipeMapRed.mapRedFinished(PipeMapRed.java:579)
    at org.apache.hadoop.streaming.PipeMapper.map(PipeMapper.java:124)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapRunner.run(MapRunner.java:50)
    at org.apache.hadoop.streaming.PipeMapRunner.run(PipeMapRunner.java:36)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.runOldMapper(MapTask.java:441)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.run(MapTask.java:377)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.Child$4.run(Child.java:255)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:396)
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1059)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.Child.main(Child.java:249)

2012-03-26 07:19:05,400 INFO org.apache.hadoop.streaming.PipeMapRed (main): mapRedFinished
2012-03-26 07:19:05,400 WARN org.apache.hadoop.streaming.PipeMapRed (main): java.io.IOException: Bad file descriptor
    at java.io.FileOutputStream.writeBytes(Native Method)
    at java.io.FileOutputStream.write(FileOutputStream.java:282)
    at java.io.BufferedOutputStream.write(BufferedOutputStream.java:105)
    at java.io.BufferedOutputStream.flushBuffer(BufferedOutputStream.java:65)
    at java.io.BufferedOutputStream.flush(BufferedOutputStream.java:123)
    at java.io.DataOutputStream.flush(DataOutputStream.java:106)
    at org.apache.hadoop.streaming.PipeMapRed.mapRedFinished(PipeMapRed.java:579)
    at org.apache.hadoop.streaming.PipeMapper.close(PipeMapper.java:135)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapRunner.run(MapRunner.java:57)
    at org.apache.hadoop.streaming.PipeMapRunner.run(PipeMapRunner.java:36)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.runOldMapper(MapTask.java:441)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.run(MapTask.java:377)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.Child$4.run(Child.java:255)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:396)
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1059)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.Child.main(Child.java:249)

2012-03-26 07:19:05,400 INFO org.apache.hadoop.streaming.PipeMapRed (main): mapRedFinished
2012-03-26 07:19:05,405 INFO org.apache.hadoop.streaming.PipeMapRed (Thread-13): MRErrorThread done
2012-03-26 07:19:05,408 INFO org.apache.hadoop.mapred.TaskLogsTruncater (main): Initializing logs' truncater with mapRetainSize=-1 and reduceRetainSize=-1
2012-03-26 07:19:05,519 INFO org.apache.hadoop.io.nativeio.NativeIO (main): Initialized cache for UID to User mapping with a cache timeout of 14400 seconds.
2012-03-26 07:19:05,520 INFO org.apache.hadoop.io.nativeio.NativeIO (main): Got UserName hadoop for UID 106 from the native implementation
2012-03-26 07:19:05,522 WARN org.apache.hadoop.mapred.Child (main): Error running child
java.io.IOException: log:null
R/W/S=7018/3/0 in:NA [rec/s] out:NA [rec/s]
minRecWrittenToEnableSkip_=9223372036854775807 LOGNAME=null
HOST=null
USER=hadoop
HADOOP_USER=null
last Hadoop input: |null|
last tool output: |text/html    1|
Date: Mon Mar 26 07:19:05 UTC 2012
java.io.IOException: Broken pipe
    at java.io.FileOutputStream.writeBytes(Native Method)
    at java.io.FileOutputStream.write(FileOutputStream.java:282)
    at java.io.BufferedOutputStream.write(BufferedOutputStream.java:105)
    at java.io.BufferedOutputStream.flushBuffer(BufferedOutputStream.java:65)
    at java.io.BufferedOutputStream.write(BufferedOutputStream.java:109)
    at java.io.DataOutputStream.write(DataOutputStream.java:90)
    at org.apache.hadoop.streaming.io.TextInputWriter.writeUTF8(TextInputWriter.java:72)
    at org.apache.hadoop.streaming.io.TextInputWriter.writeValue(TextInputWriter.java:51)
    at org.apache.hadoop.streaming.PipeMapper.map(PipeMapper.java:109)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapRunner.run(MapRunner.java:50)
    at org.apache.hadoop.streaming.PipeMapRunner.run(PipeMapRunner.java:36)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.runOldMapper(MapTask.java:441)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.run(MapTask.java:377)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.Child$4.run(Child.java:255)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:396)
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1059)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.Child.main(Child.java:249)


    at org.apache.hadoop.streaming.PipeMapper.map(PipeMapper.java:125)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapRunner.run(MapRunner.java:50)
    at org.apache.hadoop.streaming.PipeMapRunner.run(PipeMapRunner.java:36)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.runOldMapper(MapTask.java:441)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.run(MapTask.java:377)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.Child$4.run(Child.java:255)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:396)
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1059)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.Child.main(Child.java:249)
2012-03-26 07:19:05,525 INFO org.apache.hadoop.mapred.Task (main): Runnning cleanup for the task
2012-03-26 07:19:05,526 INFO org.apache.hadoop.mapred.DirectFileOutputCommitter (main): Nothing to clean up on abort since there are no temporary files written
```

Here is `mapper.py`.  Note that I write to stderr to provide myself with debugging info:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import sys
from warc import ARCFile

def main():
    warc_file = ARCFile(fileobj=sys.stdin)
    for web_page in warc_file:
        print >> sys.stderr, '%s\t%s' % (web_page.header.content_type, 1) #For debugging
        print '%s\t%s' % (web_page.header.content_type, 1)
    print >> sys.stderr, 'done' #For debugging
if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Here is what I get in the stderr for the task attempt when the mapper.py is run:

```
text/html   1
text/html   1
text/html   1
```

Basically, the loop runs through 3 times and then stops abruptly without python throwing any error.  (Note: it *should* be outputting thousands of lines).  Even an uncaught exception should appear in stderr.

Because the MapReduce runs completely fine on my local computer, my guess is that this is a problem with how Hadoop is dealing with the output I'm printing from mapper.py.  But I'm clueless as to what the problem could be.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Your streaming process (your Python script) is terminating prematurely.  This may be do to it thinking input is complete (e.g. interpreting an EOF) or a swallowed exception.  Either way, Hadoop is trying to feed into via STDIN to your script, but since the application has terminated (and thus STDIN is no longer a valid File Descriptor), you're getting a BrokenPipe error.  I would suggest adding stderr traces in your script to see what line of input is causing the problem.  Happy coding,

-Geoff

Comment: babonk, can you provide details as to how you solved your problem using this advice?

Comment: Same.  I apparently have a similar error here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18556270/aws-elastic-mapreduce-doesnt-seem-to-be-correctly-converting-the-streaming-to-j, and given that it works when piped, I'm at a loss for how to "fix" it for streaming.

Answer (score 8):

This is said in the accepted error, but let me attempt to clarify--you must block on stdin, even if you don't need it!  This is *not* the same as Linux pipes, so don't let that fool you.  What happens, intuitively, is, Streaming stands up your executable, then says, "wait here while I go get input for you".  If your executable stops for any reason before Streaming sends you 100% of the input, Streaming says, "Hey, where did that executable go that I stood up?...Hmmmm...the pipe is broken, let me raise that exception!"  So, here is some python code, all it does is what cat does, but you'll note, this code won't exit until all input is processed, and that is the key point:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import sys

while True:
    s = sys.stdin.readline()
    if not s:
        break
    sys.stdout.write(s)
```

Comment: I was getting this error because I was doing nothing with input. I added this code (even though it does nothing for me) and the error went.

Answer (score 1):

I have no experience with Hadoop on AWS but I had the same error on a regular hadoop cluster - and in my case the problem was how I started python `-mapper ./mapper.py -reducer ./reducer.py` worked but `-mapper python mapper.py` didn't.

You also seem to use a non-standard python package `warc` do you submit the necessary files to the streamjob? `-cacheFiles` or `-cacheArchive` could be helpful.

Comment: How do you include non-standard python packages?  The AWS elastic mapreduce in particular does not seem to make options like cachefiles available.